# Populando Select com valor de outro Select no Modal

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Boas.

Estou em uma parte do meu projeto onde criei um formulário com 4 opções de select com valores do Banco Mysql. sendo que são populados com valor do select anterior, trabalhando no primeiro modal, funciona perfeito, mas ao abrir o segundo modal, não é executada a função por Javascript. 
Tenho o seguinte código no formulario

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="<?php echo $clies['idpdv'];?>">
<div id="n_valo" class="col-md-12">             
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Fabricante: </label>
            <select name="id_fabr_ver" class="form-control" id="id_fabr_ver" required>
                <option value="">Escolha o Fabricante</option>
                <?php
                    $result_cat_post = "SELECT * FROM cf_fabric ORDER BY nome_fabric";
                    $resultado_cat_post = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cat_post);

                    while($row_cat_post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_cat_post) ) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row_cat_post['nome_fabric'].'">'.$row_cat_post['nome_fabric'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Equipamento:</label>
            <span class="carregando">Aguarde, carregando...</span>
            <select name="id_equip_ver" class="form-control" id="id_equip_ver" required>
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Modelo:</label>
            <span class="carregando">Aguarde, carregando...</span>
            <select name="id_modelo_ver" class="form-control" id="id_modelo_ver" required >
                <option value="">Selecione Modelo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Versão: </label>
            <span class="carregando">Aguarde, carregando...</span>
            <select name="id_versao_sat" class="form-control" id="id_versao_sat" required >
                <option value="">Selecione Versao</option>
            </select>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>                                      
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-outline-success btn-sm" name="salva_equip_cli"  id="btn-salvar" >Salvar </button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

A função em Script funciona assim.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function (){

    $('#id_fabr_ver').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val()) {                
            $('#id_equip_ver').hide();
            $('.carregandover').show();
            $('#id_modelo_ver').hide();
            $('.carregandover').show();
            $('#id_versao_sat').hide();
            $('.carregandover').show();
            $('#id_layout_sat').hide();
            $('.carregandover').show();
            $.getJSON('busca_ver.php?search=',{id_fabr_ver: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){

                var options = '<option value="">Selecione Equipamento </option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].nome_fabrica + '" >' + j[i].descricao + '</option>';
                }   
                $('#id_equip_ver').html(options).show();
                $('.carregandover').hide();
                $('#id_modelo_ver').html(options).show();
                $('.carregandover').hide();
                $('#id_versao_sat').html(options).show();
                $('.carregandover').hide();
                $('#id_layout_sat').html(options).show();
                $('.carregandover').hide();
            });
            } else {
            $('#id_equip_ver').html('<option value="">– Escolha Fabricante –</option>');
            $('#id_modelo_ver').html('<option value="">– Escolha Equipamento –</option>');
            $('#id_versao_sat').html('<option value="">– Escolha Modelo –</option>');
            $('#id_layout_sat').html('<option value="">– Layout  –</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Nesse modelo ao acessar o primeiro modal, onde a ID fica dentro de uma Tabela.
a quantidade de linhas varia com cada *cliente.

chamo o modal da seguinte forma

```
<i class="fa fa-edit" data-placement="top" title="Editar SAT"  data-toggle='modal' data-target=".alt_sat<?php echo $clies["id"]; ?>">BOTAO PARA CHAMAR MODAL</i>
```

Corpo do modal

```
<div class="modal fade alt_sat<?php echo $clies["id"];?>"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="alt_sat<?php echo $clies["id"];?>" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered ">---CONTEUDO DA MODAL-----</div></div>
```

Alguma dica como faço para abrir a segunda modal que a id vem da variável, e conseguir popular os select?

Answer (score 0):

Comunidade, Após alguns dias, consegui resolver da seguinte.

Alterei para

```
<select class="form-control" id="id_modelo_sat<?php echo $cxes['idv'];?>" required >
```

Selecione Modelo

tambem adicione a variavel no Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){ // funcao para buscar as versoes do modelo selecionado anteriormente
    $('#id_modelo_sat<?php echo $cxes['idv'];?>').change(function(){
        if( $(this).val()) {...
```

como estava usando o script em outra pagina estava errando no include após o .

Agradeço todos...